# How to scrape the content from all the div tags which also contain another tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The website I am trying to scrape has all of its content laid out under the same `div` class type: `mock-div`. Upon inspecting its HTML, the relevant content is only present under those `div` tags which also contain the `figure` tag. What should be the correct XPath?

I tried to see if the following would work

```
response.xpath("//figure~//").getall()
```

but it returns `ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //figure~//` and rightly so.

```
<div class="mock-div">
    <h2 class="mock-h2" id="id1"> hello world </h2>
    <figure class="mock-fig"><img src="file.jpg" alt="filename">
    <figcaption>file caption</figcaption> </figure>
    <p>text1</p>
    <p>text2</p>

</div>
...
<div class="mock-div">
    <h2 class="mock-h2" id="id2"> footer </h2>
    <p> end of the webpage </p>
```

From the HTML above, we want to extract from all the matching `div` tag the following information:

1. `<h2>` tag: hello world
2. `<p>` tag: text1, text2
3. src value from `img` tag: file.jpg
4. alt value from `img` tag: filename
5. `figcaption` tag: file caption

Comment: @Alexander : Can't use the class because the footer div has the same id has the above divs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `class` as the xpath identifier.

```
for section in response.xpath('//div[@class="mock-div"]'):
    h2 = section.xpath('./h2/text()').get()
    p_s = section.xpath('./p/text()').getall()
    src = section.xpath('.//img/@src').get()
    alt = section.xpath('.//img/@alt').get()
    fig_caption = section.xpath('.//figcaption/text()').get()
```

---

Here is an example that uses the method you described, by grabbing the parent `div` of the `figure` elements.  You would simply use the `..`  xpath selector to grab the parent of the `figure` element.

For example:

```
import scrapy

html = """
<div class="mock-div">
    <h2 class="mock-h2" id="id1"> hello world </h2>
    <figure class="mock-fig"><img src="file.jpg" alt="filename">
    <figcaption>file caption</figcaption> </figure>
    <p>text1</p>
    <p>text2</p>

</div>
"""
html = scrapy.Selector(text=html)



for elem in html.xpath("//figure"):
    section = elem.xpath('./..')
    print({
    'h2': section.xpath('./h2/text()').get(),
    'p_s': section.xpath('./p/text()').getall(),
    'src': section.xpath('.//img/@src').get(),
    'alt': section.xpath('.//img/@alt').get(),
    'fig_caption': section.xpath('.//figcaption/text()').get() })
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'h2': ' hello world ', 'p_s': ['text1', 'text2'], 'src': 'file.jpg', 'alt': 'filename', 'fig_caption': 'file caption'}
```

This isn't a strategy that I would usually recommend though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XPath Axes for this. For example, this XPath will get all `div` tags that contain a `figure` tag:

```
response.xpath("//div[descendant::figure]").getall()
```

### XPath Axes

> An axis represents a relationship to the context (current) node, and
> is used to locate nodes relative to that node on the tree.

### `descendant`

> Selects all descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) of the current
> node

---

**See also:**

- [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)
- [XPath Axes and their Shortcuts](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/templating/macros/xslt/xpath-axes-and-their-shortcuts)